# C++ MultiThreading giving different result

Tags: c++, multithreading, for-loop, openmp, pragma

I'm a bit new to multithreading in C++ and I'm just trying to complete some simple for loops using OMP. For this function specifically, an array of user specified size `n` is filled with random integers between 0 to 99 (inclusive). The sum of this array is then computed once with a normal `for` loop and again with a `#pragma omp parallel for` loop. For some reason, as `n` gets larger, the functions are returning different results. For example, when `n = 10`, here's the output:

```
REGULAR FOR LOOP SUM: 1216
REGULAR FOR LOOP RUNNING TIME: 0.000003

OMP FOR LOOP SUM: 1216
OMP FOR LOOP RUNNING TIME: 0.000205
```

When `n = 100`, here's the output:

```
REGULAR FOR LOOP SUM: 4946
REGULAR FOR LOOP RUNNING TIME: 0.000003

OMP FOR LOOP SUM: 3999
OMP FOR LOOP RUNNING TIME: 0.000247
```

Here's my code for the `REGULAR FOR LOOP`:

```
int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum += A[i];
  }
  return(sum);
```

And here's my code for the `OMP FOR LOOP`:

```
int sum = 0;
  int i;
#pragma omp parallel shared(A, n) private(i) num_threads(4)
  {
    #pragma omp for
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      sum += A[i];
    }
  }
  return(sum);
```

Why is the `OMP FOR LOOP` returning a different sum for `n = 100`? Also, why is the running time for `OMP FOR LOOP` greater than `REGULAR FOR LOOP`? Isn't the point of multithreading to reduce runtime?

Comment: For the second part, when using OMP you have to spawn new threads, which adds overhead. Multi-threading is only advantageous if the overhead is less than the cost of just doing the loop. Try numbers in the billions, and you'll probably get a difference. That being said, with vectorization, a simple loop is likely parallel (in a way) already in your case.

Comment: Also, using your code, I get the same answers for both. Is the A array the same between the two?

Comment: When you omit a required reduction clause any

Comment: If the question is to be called stupid it might be rephrased as why not use the reduction clause. If you are interested in gaining performance the question becomes somewhat more complex. Even at loop count 100 simd optimization may not gain and omp parallel probably loses performance.   For simd optimization alone depending on your compiler omp simd reduction may not work as well as auto vectorization.

Comment: @Zulan The accepted answer for that did in fact work. It appears the reduction clause was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition for `sum`:

```
sum += A[i];
```

Here multipe threads read from `sum` and write a new value from it. You may lose some increments here if another thread does its increments based on a value thats about to be overwritten by another.

You need mutex here or use atomic increments.